# composer never completes successfully

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm using composer with symfony and I found out that after I install or update any new bundle by running `composer update` it copies things to respective folders but throws few errors before completing the process.

> Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies
>     - Installing knplabs/knp-components (dev-master 163308e)
>       Cloning 163308ed3442e7e9ec4a45ff912664e366954c82
>
> - Installing knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle (dev-master 0d719a9)
>     Cloning 0d719a9bd6973bde1b10587fc2c85cf04c5e0e9d
>
> Writing lock file Generating autoload files PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   'Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader' not  found in
>   E:\workspace\sadi\projects\thook\app\autoload.php on line 6 PHP Stack
>   trace: PHP   1. {main}()
>   E:\workspace\sadi\projects\thook\vendor\sensio\distribution-bu
>   ndle\Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Resources\bin\build_bootstrap.php:0
>   PHP   2. require_once()
>   E:\workspace\sadi\projects\thook\vendor\sensio\distribut
>   ion-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Resources\bin\build_bootstrap.php:24
>
> Fatal error: Class
>   'Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader' not foun d in
>   E:\workspace\sadi\projects\thook\app\autoload.php on line 6
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0002     633136   1. {main}() E:\workspace\sadi\projects\thook\vendor\sens
>   io\distribution-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Resources\bin\build_boot
>   strap.php:0
>       0.0216     652848   2. require_once('E:\workspace\sadi\projects\thook\app\au toload.php')
>   E:\workspace\sadi\projects\thook\vendor\sensio\distribution-bundle\
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Resources\bin\build_bootstrap.php:24
>
> Script
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
>   h andling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception
>
> [RuntimeException]   An error occurred when generating the bootstrap
>   file.
>
> update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]
>   [--no-custom-instal lers] [--no-scripts] [-v|--verbose]
>   [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [ packagesN]

Why is that?

Comment: which version of the symfony standard edition do you have? There was a  bug in the latest `2.1.6` version which is fixed yesterday

Comment: It would be better if you post the whole commands used to update Symfony, e.g.: `php composer.phar update symfony/symfony`, as well as the composer file.

Comment: Please run composer with the `--no-scripts`. If it executes correctly, the problem lies in symfony2 which has some misconfiguration it seems. If the problem persists, there is an issue with composer. Please update your post accordingly to investigate further.

Comment: @WouterJ seemed to be a bug that was fixed later by symfony team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be a bug that was fixed later by symfony team. Thanks @Wouter J

Comment: I still get the same error. I cannot generate bootstrap file. I am using symfony 2.0